# Algorithm to adaptively sample a function

Tags: algorithm, sampling, curve

I am looking for some algorithm that could sample a function based on its curvature. E.g. for some interval `[a,b]` and a given number of samples `n` the algorithm would sample the function in such a way that more samples will be placed where the functions bends, and less samples where the function is more "linear".

The graphical representation of what I have in mind is presented in the picture below:

[image: adaptive sampling example]

Comment: It is a hard problem, a classic problem of finite-element and Fredholm analyses. The problem has no known general solution as far as I am aware, though various heuristics have been tried with various success. As a graduate student, I once spent nearly a month trying to get this to work. You might try extracting a Fourier spectrum from the curve but, regardless of what you try, this won't be easy to do well.

Comment: As thb said, the general problem is hard. But maybe you can extract some knowledge by identifying the classes of functions you're trying to sample. To improve this question you should give a more complete problem description.

Comment: @thb: can you substantiate ? IMO the RDP algorithm (see Matt's answer) is a very effective and straightforward solution. No general relativity nor hyperfractals involved.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ha! I should have liked to try that when I was in graduate school! No, I had not known about that, nor had my research mates, but it looks pretty good. Maybe it did not apply to our problem for some reason I do not know but, more likely, it just was not in use in our field, so we did not know about it. Too late for me. Thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust RDP is an algorithm where you start with a number of samples and you reject some of them. As the problem is stated it is unclear if those samples are cheap or even if a proper minimum sampling rate exists: like how'd you get exactly `n` samples spread optimally using RDP? The algorithm isn't designed to actually sample a function i.e. for that purpose you'd need to extend it by a cost maximisation function to compute the farthest point from the line segment connecting two points on the curve.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: if `n` is imposed (and for this problem, the maximum deviation would certainly be a much better criterion, I am sure the OP is unaware), no real harm is done by halving `n` on every recursion level. Trying to find the exact optimum is overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common operation in computer graphics is "flattening" a curved path, i.e., approximating a curve by line segments.

There is usually a constraint on how far the approximation is allowed to deviate from the original curve and so the result looks a lot like what you're asking for, with samples more concentrated in the areas of highest curvature.

So you could try one of the algorithms that is used for this purpose, like the RDP algorithm described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: A caveat: often (as in the given example), the unit lengths are not equal on both axis. The computation of the distance must account for this.